# How to fix fieldset width and height in Zurb foundation?

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

So the question is in the title.
In zurb foundation5 there is fieldset(pretty good looking).
But if you will take right bottom corner of filedset and drag as a result you can manipulate sizes of it.
How to fix sizes of fieldset?

Comment: Are you talking about textareas? I do not see any resizing of fieldsets in Foundation 5.2.2.

Comment: @ChrisPeters you right.